# How do I evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}dx} = \frac{\ln{5}}{4}$ using iterated integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I'm studying for quals and I'm trying to solve the following.

> Prove using the results concerning iterated integrals (i.e., you should write the integral below as a a double integral) that
>
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x}\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}dx} = \frac{\ln{5}}{4}$$
>
> (Note: In arguing for this problem, you may assume without proof that a continuous function $h : X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable with respect to the product measure if $X$ and $Y$ are Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.)

Since the problem says to use iterated integrals, I tried to use the fact that

$$e^{-x} = \int_{x}^{\infty}{-e^{-y}dy}$$

and re-write this as

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\int_{x}^{\infty}{-e^{-y}dy}\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}dx} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\int_{x}^{\infty}{-e^{-y}}\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}dydx} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\int_{0}^{y}{-e^{-y}}\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x}dxdy}.$$

But this doesn't make things any easier. I have a feeling I'm missing something important since this is a practice problem for a real analysis/measure theory qual but I don't remember/can't find any measure theory theorems that really help with this.

Comment: My immediate thought is that you can use Fubini to evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$, which suggests doing the same thing here

Answer (score 6):

Amusingly, I solved this as part of a homework assignment last semester.

The hint that I was given would probably prove helpful though: verify and use the fact that
$$
\int_0^1 e^{-y} \sin(2xy) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{1}{ye^y} \sin^2(y)
$$
Once you have this the remainder is fairly trivial, so I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 4):

Attempt:
\begin{align*}
\frac {\sin^2 x}x &= \frac {\cos (0x)- \cos (2x)}{2x - 0x}\\
&= \frac 1{2x}\int_0^{2x} \sin (t)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \frac 1{2x} \int_0^2 \sin (ux) \,\mathrm d(ux) {\quad}{[t = ux, u \in(0,2)]}\\
&=\frac 12 \int_0^2 \sin (ux)\,\mathrm du. 
\end{align*}
Then
$$
\cdots =\frac 12 \int_0^{+\infty}\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx \int_0^2\sin (ux) \,\mathrm du.
$$
If Fubini is feasible, then
\begin{align*}
\cdots&=\frac 12\int_0^2 \mathrm du\int_0^{+\infty} \mathrm e^{-x} \sin (ux)\, \mathrm dx\\
&= \frac 12 \int_0^2 \mathrm du \int_{+\infty}^0\sin (ux) \mathrm d(\mathrm e^{-x})\\
&=\frac 12 \int_0^2 \frac u{u^2 +1} \,\mathrm du{\qquad}{[\text{integration by parts}]}\\
&= \frac 14 \log(u^2 +1) \Biggr\rvert_0^2 = \boxed{\,\frac {\log 5}4\,}. 
\end{align*}

To validate the application of Fubini, note that the measurability is obvious and that $\vert \mathrm e^{-x} \sin (ux) \vert \leqslant \mathrm e^{-x}$ and that $$\int_{(u,x) \in [0,2]\times [0, +\infty)} \mathrm e^{-x}\ \mathrm dx \,\mathrm du$$ is clearly finite, thus we are done.